# How to hide the cursor when typing on android EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to hide the cursor when user types on the EditText. How can I do it?

[This cursor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kedcc.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```